# Preserving SCRIPT tags (and more) in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, regex, exception, ckeditor, source-code-protection

Is it possible to create a block of code within the CKEditor that will not be touched by the editor itself, and will be maintained in its intended-state until explicitly changed by the user? I've been attempting to input javascript variables (bound in script tags) and a flash movie following, but CKEditor continues to rewrite my pasted code/markup, and in doing so breaking my code.

I'm working with the following setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("content", {
    height : "500px",
    width : "680px",
    resize_maxWidth : "680px",
    resize_minWidth : "680px",
    toolbar :
    [
      ['Source','-','Save','Preview'],
      ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Print', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'],
      ['Undo','Redo','-','Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','RemoveFormat'],
      ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','-','Subscript','Superscript'],
      ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'],
      ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
      ['Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
      ['Image','Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar']
    ]
  });
  CKFinder.SetupCKEditor( editor, "<?php print url::base(); ?>assets/ckfinder" );
</script>
```

I suppose the most ideal solution would be to preserve the contents of any tag that contains `class="preserve"` enabling much more than the limited exclusives.

**Update**: I'm thinking the solution to this problem is in [`CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource()`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource), but my regular-expression experience is proving to be too juvenile to handle this issue. How would I go about exempting all tags that contain the 'preserved' class from being touched by CKEditor?

Comment: not sure what you are building... but if this editor accepts script tags and emits them in the output back to the page you are totally exposing your site to XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attacks.

Comment: scunliffe, That's exactly what it is. But this is taking place within an administration portion of the site. Users won't be accessing this page. I'm not worried about the security issue. Only an admin will have access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not with the CKEditor. Instead, the issue was with the MVC-Engine running the Site itself. Kohana has a `global_xss_filtering` within its configuration that is enabled by default. This prevents the submission of script tags, to prevent scripting-attacks on your site. Changing this value to `false` will permit the submission of `<script>` tags in forms, but it also opens up the site to potential security issues that can be very serious. It is advisable that you not disable `global_xss_filtering`.

```
/* /(system|application)/config/config.php - line 66 */
/**
 * Enable or disable global XSS filtering of GET, POST, and SERVER data. This
 * option also accepts a string to specify a specific XSS filtering tool.
 */
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: tch ... why didn't you add 'kohana' tag? i'm a kohana user after all, so i should have been able to help if i've known it was kohana issue. well, too bad for me i didn't get the bounty :P .. at least i learned something new nevertheless

Comment: Sorry, Lukman :) I was certain it *must* be a CKEditor issue. It wasn't until I decided to start echoing out `$_POST["element"]` instead of `$this->input->post("element")` that I realized my problem was elsewhere :) Almost immediately I thought of XSS, and went straight to the config :)

Answer (score 16):

In CKEDITOR folder you have a **config.js** file. Open it and paste the code:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = {
        script: true,
        $1: {
            // This will set the default set of elements
            elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
            attributes: true,
            styles: true,
            classes: true
        }
    };
};
```

It will allow `<script>...</script>` tags in Source mode.

Answer (score 10):

**Suggestion 1:** Create separate plain textarea for the admin to enter the scripts / HTML code.

**Suggestion 2:** Introduce a bbcode, like `[script][/script]` or `[html][/html]` that the admins can use to put the scripts / HTML code and have your server-side translate them into `<script></script>` and HTML code. Make sure when showing a saved content into the CKEditor, you need to have your server-side translate them into the bbcode first (or CKEditor will strip them out). Or the less-hassle way is to store the submitted content in the database as it is entered and only do the translation when displaying the page.

**Suggestion 3**: Since you want to use `class="preserve"` to mark tags you don't want CKEditor to strip out, then add the following JavaScript lines when initializing the editor:

```
// protect <anytag class="preserve"></anytag>
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<([\S]+)[^>]*class="preserve"[^>]*>.*<\/\1>/g );
// protect <anytag class="preserve" /><
CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<[^>]+class="preserve"[^>\/]*\/>/g );
```

Comment: The scripts go with flash elements from time to time, so they will be posted into the editor with the flash elements. Both are getting re-written by CKEditor. The code will be stored in the database, but it it being written through my admin page, using the CKEditor. I'm thinking the solution is with `CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource()` but my regex-experience is a bit dry.

Comment: Edited with `CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource()` regexes :)

Comment: Thank you, Lukman. I'll give these a whirl when I get home this evening.

Comment: I'm sorry, Lukman. I had not a chance last night to try it. I will today, surely. Thank you.

Comment: CKEditor seems to ignore this declaration, and continues to corrupt my script tags.

Comment: ... even when you put `class="preserve"` in it?

Comment: Yes. `class="preserve"` is only necessary on the outer-most tag, correct?

Comment: One thing I did change though was in your first expression, I changed `.*` to `(.|\n)*` to accommodate multiple lines. It's still erasing my script tags though.