# What browser based WYSIWYG editor respects my HTML format?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dojo, wysiwyg

What browser based WYSIWYG editor respects the HTML I type into the code view when I switch back to the WYSIWYG view? I have used the dojo based one (dijit.Editor) but that removes all tags that it does not know, and reformats my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [these](http://blog.wearepropeople.com/best-online-html-editors/) and this is not the place to ask that m8.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Where should I ask it these types of questions?

Comment: This is a forum-type question. And [SO is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best what I've used so far is CKeditor. It is not perfect, but pretty useable.

http://ckeditor.com/

You must configure it, though.

Comment: To complete your answer as OP want to protect his own code source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1753770/1414562

Answer (score 1):

Try Xinha, I think it is the best one and you can configure what kind of plugins you want to have:

http://xinha.raimundmeyer.de/x_examples/ext_example.html