# Insert javascript in to body of ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I use CKEDITOR 4.6

I set this code(Html,JavaScript) to source of CKEDITOR

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>
    <p><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert("I am an alert box!");
            }
        </script>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

But when i click on button this java script code does not worked? 
[image]
[image]

How can run javascript in CKEDITOR?

Also i set this config but still not worked

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

     config.allowedContent = {
        script: true,
        allowedContent :true,
        $1: {
            // This will set the default set of elements
            elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
            attributes: true,
            styles: true,
            classes: true
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Try to move <script> out of <p> tag.

Comment: I move <script> to header tag but still not worked...

Comment: That's weird. The code itself is working, it must be some software issue.

Comment: It seems like this editor requires some additional code for javascript to work.

Comment: what is this requires?

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739552/preserving-script-tags-and-more-in-ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things wrong with your code:
1: you shouldn't put a `<script>` tag in a `<p>` element.
2: most of the time, you need to execute your JS after the page has been loaded fully, so putting it in the header won't fix it, put it after all your content has been loaded.

sometimes, javascript won't run unless you use a localhost, try using wamp/xamp etc. if this doesn't work

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body dir="rtl">
        <p>Click the button to display an alert box:</p>
        <p><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button></p>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                alert("I am an alert box!");
            }
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```